# format date for jquery ui datepicker

Tags: jquery

i'm trying the following code but it keeps giving me syntax errror under dateformat... how can i fix this? i just need to change the format of the date

```
   var date = new Date();
        var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
        var currentDate = date.getDate();
        var currentYear = date.getFullYear();
        $('#datepicker1').datepicker({
            minDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate)
             dateFormat:"yyyymmdd"
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a comma at the end of:

```
minDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate),
                                                         ^ missing
```

Answer (score 0):

use date.js to get today, yesterday and tomorrow etc dates. it is more flexible to add dates.http://www.datejs.com/